# Need to run connection before displaying table

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I have a uitableview which i want to display the contents of an array in.

I get the data using a nsurlconnection.
The problem is the table displays before the get data method, so the table shows nothing.
How can i fix this?Not sure how to change method order...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad{
    tableview.hidden = YES;
 }
```

once parsing data completed, write a look up method for know the completion of parsing.
suppose parsing completion handler

```
-(void)parsingCompleted{
tableview.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Problem with that is it works to hide it visually but it still loads the invisible table before the parser is finished..

Comment: Get the items in array with new data and say
-(void)parsingCompleted{
tableview.hidden = NO; 
items = //Newly parsed items   , items is collection that you are using for load tableview                                             
[tableview reloadData];
}